# Correct use of numpy searchsorted routine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have an input DataFrame which I want to modify one of its 'Spcx' columns, for this I have defined an ascending sorted list 'Spaces'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
if __name__ == "__main__":

    Example = [[   0],
               [   0],
               [0.14],
               [0.10],
               [0.10],
               [0.10],
               [0.13],
               [0.16],
               [0.24],
               [0.21],
               [0.14],
               [0.14]]
            
    Example = pd.DataFrame(data = Example, columns = ['Spcx'])
    
    Spaces = [0, 0.100, 0.125, 0.150, 0.175, 0.200, 0.225, 0.250, 0.275, 0.300]

    Spaces = np.array(Spaces)  # convert to numpy array
    Example["Spcx"] = Spaces[np.searchsorted(Spaces, Example["Spcx"], side = 'left')]
```

What I am looking for is that each Example ['Spcx'] is compared with each interval of 'Spaces' and take the value on the left, for example:

0 - -> Spaces [0 - 0.100] - -> 0

0.10 - -> Spaces [0.100 - 0.125] - -> 0.100

0.14 - -> Spaces [0.125 - 0.150] - -> 0.125

It should stay like this:

```
Spcx    
0       
0       
0.125   
0.1     
0.1        
0.1      
0.125   
0.15
0.225      
0.2        
0.125   
0.125
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the numpy `digitize` function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
if __name__ == "__main__":

    Example = [[   0],
               [   0],
               [0.14],
               [0.10],
               [0.10],
               [0.10],
               [0.13],
               [0.16],
               [0.24],
               [0.21],
               [0.14],
               [0.14]]
            
    Example = pd.DataFrame(data = Example, columns = ['Spcx'])
    
    Spaces = [0, 0.100, 0.125, 0.150, 0.175, 0.200, 0.225, 0.250, 0.275, 0.300]

    Spaces = np.array(Spaces)  # convert to numpy array
    Example["Spcx"] = Spaces[np.digitize(Example["Spcx"],Spaces)-1]
    print(Example)
```

Output:

```
     Spcx
0   0.000
1   0.000
2   0.125
3   0.100
4   0.100
5   0.100
6   0.125
7   0.150
8   0.225
9   0.200
10  0.125
11  0.125
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach, is simply to do use `side='right'` and subtract 1:

```
Spaces = np.array(Spaces)  # convert to numpy array
Example["Spcx"] = Spaces[np.searchsorted(Spaces, Example["Spcx"], side='right') - 1]
print(Example)
```

**Output**

```
     Spcx
0   0.000
1   0.000
2   0.125
3   0.100
4   0.100
5   0.100
6   0.125
7   0.150
8   0.225
9   0.200
10  0.125
11  0.125
```

From the documentation on [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), assuming that `a` is sorted array, it will return:

| side | returned index i satisfies |
| --- | --- |
| left | a[i-1] < v <= a[i] |
| **right** | **a[i-1] <= v < a[i]** |

Basically `"right"` will return `i` such that `i - 1` corresponds to the last value that less or equal to the one is searching.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pd.cut` with `right` option:

```
Spaces[pd.cut(Example['Spcx'], Spaces, right=False, labels=False)]
```

Output:

```
array([0.   , 0.   , 0.125, 0.1  , 0.1  , 0.1  , 0.125, 0.15 , 0.225,
       0.2  , 0.125, 0.125])
```